# Ray tranformation with column dtype list<element: double not null>

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

My dataset schema is the following in ray:

```
Column  Type
------  ----
x_1     list<element: double not null>
x_2     list<element: double not null>
y       int32
```

Right now if I try to convert this to a tensorflow object, I get the following dtypes:

```
data.to_tf(feature_columns=["x_1", "x_2"], label_columns="y")
<_OptionsDataset element_spec=({'x_1': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='x_1'), 'x_2': TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.string, name='x_2')}, TensorSpec(shape=(None,), dtype=tf.int32, name='y'))>
```

As you can see it converts to the features to a string type by default. I need a shape of `(25, 2)` where 25 is the length of the list and 2 is the features `x_1` and `x_2`. How do I convert the data to the right format?

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
from typing import Any, Dict
import numpy as np
def transform(row):
    row['X'] = np.array([row['x_1'], row['x_2']]).T
    return row
data.map(transform)
```